# Webivew onNavigationStateChange method call multiple time in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview

I am making react native application and one screen I am used webview for that and I want to handle onNavigationStateChange props one time call right now it is calling multiple times so any idea how can I solve this issue. refer below code

```
<WebView 
         ref={r => this.webview = r}
         style={{width:globals.screenWidth, height:globals.screenHeight}}
         bounces={false}
         style={{ flex: 1 }}
         startInLoadingState
         scalesPageToFit
         javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
         javaScriptEnabled={true}
         domStorageEnabled = {true}
         onNavigationStateChange={data =>
            this.handleNavigationStateChange(data)
        }
         onLoadStart={() => {
             console.log("onLoadStart-->");
         }}
         onLoadEnd={() => {
            console.log("onLoadEnd-->");
         }}
         source={{uri: globals.MYURL}}
         onError={(error) => this.onError()}
        />


handleNavigationStateChange = navState => {
    console.log("navState >>>>" + JSON.stringify(navState));

};
```

When i run above code navState >>>> print 3 times I want to handle it 1 time so how can I solve this issue? Your all suggestions are appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

i've got same issue but i move the handle to onLoadEnd

```
_onLoadEndHandle = (input) => {
   console.log(input.nativeEvent)
   if (input.nativeEvent.url.toLowerCase().includes('?type=print')) {
     console.log('printing...')
     this._print() // Calling printing function
   }
}
```

I hope this will help you.